# Why am I getting value error when converting list of strings to int

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

```
def answer(l):
# your code here
   l1=[]
   l2=[]
   l0=[]
   l.sort(reverse=True)
   for i in l:
       if i%3==0:
         l0.append(i)
       elif i%3==1:
         l1.append(i)
       elif i%3==2:
          l2.append(i)
   if(sum(l)%3==0):
      return int(''.join(str(e) for e in l))
   elif sum(l)%3==1:
      if l1!=[]:
         l1.pop()
      else:
          if len(l2)>=2:
              l2.pop()
              l2.pop()
          else:
              return 0
   elif sum(l)%3==2:
       if l2!=[]:
         l2.pop()
       else:
          if len(l1)>=2:
              l1.pop()
              l1.pop()
          else:
              return 0  
   l1.extend(l2)
   l1.extend(l0)

   l1.sort(reverse=True)
   return int(''.join(str(e) for e in l1))
```

The l1 list needs to be converted to string and then to int, but I am getting value error. Can I know why?
inputs:(int list) [3 , 1 ,4,1]
output:(int)      4331

Comment: What is `l1`? Currently it is hard to guess the mistake.

Comment: Please provide sample `l1` , specific error message, and required output.

Comment: yeah i have made change's could you please check it ?

Answer (score 3):

The string representation of some element of `l1` does not match `^[0-9]+$`.

That's why you get a `ValueError`.

Comment: @tevemadar yes, the final `''.join` should look like `^-?[0-9]+$`, but only the first item can have a `-` prefix

Comment: @AkshayMakutam please post the part where you call the function. it works for me

Comment: @AkshayMakutam what site?